# Blueprint CSS - pages not inheriting from application layout page

Tags: layout, blueprint-css

I have the following in my application layout page

```
<body>
 <div class="container showgrid">
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  <section>
    <%= yield %>
  </section>
  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
 </div>
</body>
```

In my home page, I have the following code:

```
  <div class="span-12">
   <h1>Text here</h1>
  </div>  

  <div class="span-11 last">
    <h2>Text here</h2>

    <h4>Text here</h4>

    <blockquote>"Text"</br>
    -Text              
    </blockquote>

    <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path, :class => "signup-button" %>  
  </div>
```

The problem I am having is that the  css is a white block where the main content is boxed, but in the home page, the white box doesn't extend down to cover the whole home page content even though it's yielded from the application layout page inside the .

When I put  on the top of the home page, the problem is gone.  I am curious as to know what that is and if that is within the specific rules and guidelines of how to use blueprint.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed it by setting the div class to "container".  That fixed the problem